# Failed to excecute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.8.v20171121:run

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jetty

I am doing a JavaEE HelloWorld application using jettty as maven plugin. When I try to run jetty, I get this following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.8.v20171121:run (default-cli) on project HomeShop: Failure
```

Here my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>HomeShop</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
enter code here
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am working with IntelliJ

May someone can help me to fix this problem

Comment: Please include more of the logging output, there's something telling you why it failed likely earlier.  Also, you can run Maven with `--debug` or `-X` to get reams of more output (not appropriate to paste here) that you might see more detail on why it failed.

Comment: there is no other details in logging output besides  "Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.8.v20171121:run (default-cli) on project HomeShop: Failure"

Comment: Then try upgrading to Jetty `9.4.22.v20191022`, there should be more detail on why.